# Wifi icon is not displayed

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, icons, indicator

My networking status is on which is shown in first figure
[image: Network]
But the Networking icon i.e. the wifi icon is missing. How do I bring it back?

[image: Wierless Icon is missing]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run this command from the terminal, just copy and paste for accuracy.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

This should work if you uninstalled the icon by mistake.

Comment: YESS!!! I've tried sooo many 'fixes' and this one finally did the trick!! FYI I also needed to reboot after this. THANK YOU!

Comment: When I try the cmd, I get the below error. Can someone help in resolving please.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 network-manager-gnome : Depends: libnm-gtk0 (= 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4) but 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.5 is to be installed

Answer (score 19):

It could be very well possible that your `nm-applet` application has been killed or crashed.

Try running this command in a terminal:

```
nohup nm-applet &
```

if you don't want nohup.out file, you can use

```
nohup nm-applet > /dev/null &
```

Comment: This was the one that worked for me.  I did not have an Internet connection and was disconnected from my router, so I could not use `apt-get` to reinstall the network manager.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

this fixed it for me...

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
```