# skype and thunderbird indicators missing after 14.04 updates

Tags: 14.04, indicator, skype, thunderbird, system-tray

I recently (max 5 days ago) installed few updates on my Ubuntu 14.04 and now both thunderbird and skype indicators are missing from my top bar.
I was using dconf editor and I inserted 'All' (lowcase too) into whitelist

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Check this out [http://askubuntu.com/a/578959/408347][1]. That helped me also with HipChat icon.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/578959/408347

Comment: I recently installed ubuntu 15.04, so I cannot try any solution. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This command should re-enable missing indicators :

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
```

Answer (score 0):

If other icons are showing there on top bar of your desktop then simply press ALT+Rightclick OR Alt+win+Rightclick on top bar and select add to panel and select skype and thunderbird there.

If above steps not solving issue go with following command:
 apt-get install indicator-applet-complete .